# Reproduce/transfer a process using psutil

Tags: python, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, scheduling, psutil

I am working on a cluster computing project. I need to monitor the processes running on the cpu, and transfer  non system processes to another computer on the network. I can monitor them using psutil library but, is there a way by which I can get enough information about a process and the data being used and then execute that on another computer on the network. Can I do this with psutil or another such library in Python or any other language.

Comment: Normally, no, this isn't feasible. Generally, the software or the environment would need to be specifically designed for this eventuality. The design itself is pretty straightforward though. Design the software with the capability to save/load its state. Once the software has that capability, it's just a matter of telling it to save its state and terminate, transfer the state data to the other machine, then starting up another instance of the software on the new machine, pointing it to the state data to recover from. Platforms like Docker can help enable this functionality.

Comment: Is the such Process-under-Review a python process? Python interpreter state can get saved (stored), state-fully, transferred and "re-incarnated" on a remote device.

Comment: Also if I get the process executable and environment variables using psutil and send them to a remote computer and execute it there. Will it work ??(I'm ok if the process begins from the start instead of resuming), are there any other components that I need to send to achieve this, also are there any exceptions to this.